# Will a company change a posted job description to reflect a candidate's salary request?

Tags: salary, united-states, hiring-process, contractors, job-description

A month into a six month contract-to-hire role, it was communicated to me by my contracting agency and the company I work with that, should I accept, a process would begin to buy-out my contract and covert me to a full time position. As far as contract roles go, this is my first where there was an intention to hire.

The company's recruiter called me up and explained that the team wanted to extend an offer. The benefits were explained and then an expected salary ranged was requested of me. I responded with what I felt was an educated figure. It didn't sound too absurd -- it's grossly 3% higher (or 7% after considering benefits) than I've consistently been making as a contractor these past few years. Additionally, this number reflected my expectation that they would counter and maybe allow for me to negotiation relocation assistance (to a major city in a new state).

The recruiter said that this salary is, "higher than the max amount afforded for the salary band" of the position I would hold. I expected a counter offer, even eagerly stated that I was flexible; instead they told me that they'd be in touch and promptly ended the call.

A few weeks later, the recruiter touches base to say that they're updating the job description to "reflect the new language" and that no action items were needed on my part.

Is updating a job description to reflect a higher salary band something that actually happens?

Comment: Did they say anything that actually suggests they were planning on changing the _remuneration_ part of the the job description? Without more context, "reflect the new language" is a completely empty phrase that could mean anything.

Answer (score 4):

If the hirer is government, academic or unionized there may be agreed pay bands for certain jobs. Such employers can't arbitrarily change the limits. In order to pay you the amount you want they may have to redefine the level or responsibilities of the job. This seems to be something they are willing to do which is a great sign.

It's unusual but not unheard of. The only downside is that it may take a while.

Answer (score 2):

It may depend on your industry, but I would expect a contractor to be paid substantially more than a full time employee. That's because a permanent employee gets paid annual leave, pension contributions, and a whole bunch of other benefits. They also expect better job security. A contractor has to fund everything themselves, and will be dropped at the end of a project.

So to ask for 3% more on conversion to a permanent employee is probably wildly optimistic.

Comment: Note that OP's "contracting agency" may be their real employer (administratively speaking), in which case OP would already be earning a FTE's wage rather than the generally higher cost of a contractor. If OP is contractually employed by that agency, the agency is skimming the higher contractor costs off the top, and "what OP's been making" (as per OP's phrasing) would then not include the extra money a contractor makes (compared to an FTE).

Comment: @Flater is correct. I gross ~$120K a year, including benefits and counting for the fact that I don’t get paid PTO for the 10 or so standard holidays. I asked for ~$123K, expecting them to go as low as $111K. I always ask for the higher tail-end of what I think is market standard, considering companies usually offer the lower tail-end as the first figure in a negotiation. I didn’t include the new company’s 10% annual bonus as those aren’t stable and based on company metrics, which in my experience are always moving targets with bars being raised every year.

Comment: @Flater Good point. I was assuming an independent self-employed contractor, rather than someone working through an agency.